# kendo UI Scheduler Add but keep window open

Tags: kendo-ui, scheduler

I am using a template for adding/editing an event. What I would like to do is be able to add an event but keep the window open and retain the entered data so the user can change a couple of fields and save that other event. There are 2 save buttons, "SAVE", and "SAVE and ADD NEW". The first button will save the entered event and close the dialog window. The second button will save the entered event but will keep the window open, user changes one or more fields, then save that new event (repeat as necessary).

Any advice or pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the "save" event of the Scheduler to make copy of current event and then call the "addEvent" method of the Scheduler with it. Check the Scheduler API below:

- [Scheduler: API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler)